# how to list every single piece of information residing in gvfs-metadata?

Tags: gvfs, metadata

Using `gio info` all we can get is info about a single (and very specific) file or, at most, files in a single (and very specific) folder.
So many files exist in `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata` folder (mine has more than 500).
Is there any way to list every single piece of information "hidden" in that folder?

More clearly: **IF** gvfs metadata holds info **only based** on file or folder name, then how to list all files or folders which are included in gvfs's metadata binaries (and logs) in user's `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata` folder?